# DirectoryInfo - FileNotFound although file exists

Tags: c#, .net

I have already searched for solutions here, but I did not find any. :(
So, my problem is that I am trying to get all subdirectories in a directory and then I want to read out a file in each of these subdirectories.

This is my code: (The file I want to read out is called "info.txt")

```
string projectsPath = Path.Combine(Program.Path, "Projects");
string projectPath = Path.Combine(projectsPath, ProjectName);
string packagesFolder = Path.Combine(projectPath, "Packages");

DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(packagesFolder);
DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = dInfo.GetDirectories();

foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subDirs)
{
    string packageInfo = String.Empty;
    string[] information;

    if (dir.EnumerateFiles().Any(item => item.Name == "info.txt"))
    {
        FileInfo file = dir.EnumerateFiles().First(item => item.Name == "info.txt");

        using (StreamReader sr = file.OpenText())
        {
            packageInfo = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

So, at the top I am declaring the paths (they are correct), then I want to get all directories of the **packagesFolder** and iterate through them. 
Then I want to get the file called **info.txt** and read it out and save the content in the **packageInfo**-variable.

The problem now is that it never reaches the If-query because he cannot find the file.
I debugged it and took a look into the variables... I copied the **dir.FullName**-path and pasted it into the Windows explorer and the file opened up.

I should also have the permissions to read there, I checked, or how could I very exactly check that?
Am I using DirectoryInfo wrong or where is my mistake? Of course I also tried to get some output if the whole directory exists and it said "false", but, as I said, if I paste exactly this path in the Explorer it opens up the file.

Help would be appreciated.

Here are the paths:

**subDirs** is an array of DirectoryInfos with content: **0.1.0.0** (name of the only folder inside the **packagesFolder**).

**file** is not initialized, because the query is never reached. (FileNotFound)

All following variables of type "string" are null, because they are not initialized then.

Comment: What value does packagesFolder hold?

Comment: It is: C.\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\MyProject\Projects\Testproject\Packages, so that path is correct.

Comment: Is there only one info.txt in all of the directories?  Or is there one in each subdirectory?

Comment: There is one in each subdirectory.

Comment: Info.txt, info.txt, info.TXT ? check the case sensitivity :p  `item.Name.ToUpper() == "INFO.TXT"`

Comment: Of course I was so smart to do this ;) The file is called "info.txt".

Comment: are you looking for C.\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\MyProject\Projects\Testproject\Packages\info.txt or C.\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\MyProject\Projects\Testproject\Packages\Something\info.txt ?

Comment: Second one. C.\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\MyProject\Projects\Testproject\Packages\Something\in‌​fo.txt

Comment: Try dInfo.Exists() before enumerating it.

Comment: Did that @jle and it is available/the result was "true".

Comment: Your code has no problem.

Comment: are you sure the file name is "info.txt" with no white space, strange chars, and all in lower case ? I only see that cases on my local tests

Comment: Yes I am sure. It is exactly that name.

Comment: `EnumerateFiles()` return nothing or throw a (silent) exception ?

Comment: The if-query is never reached, so it does not give any exception or something, but it cannot find the file, so it never reaches it.

Comment: Problem solved. The problem was that I created the text file manually just for testing this and I gave it the name "info.txt", but it was already a text file -> Name should be "info.txt.txt" then. So, .NET does not lie, but thanks for your help!

Comment: good it solved and my  guess was right that name / path was problem

Comment: Yes, the problem was, I did not think that there is a problem, because everything seemed normal and I did not think about the fact that the extension is already given ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was that I created the text file manually just for testing this and I gave it the name "info.txt", but it was already a text file -> Name should be "info.txt.txt" then. So, .NET does not lie, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var file = dir.GetFiles("info.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).First();
```

Alternatively, you could use EnumerateFiles in the place of GetFiles.

Edit:
Check if infoFiles contains anything after this:

```
string projectsPath = Path.Combine(Program.Path, "Projects");
string projectPath = Path.Combine(projectsPath, ProjectName);
string packagesFolder = Path.Combine(projectPath, "Packages");

DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(packagesFolder);
var infoFiles = dInfo.GetFiles("info.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: It tells me: "The sequence does not contain any elements".

Comment: does this not mean that info.txt not available in the location it is searching for ? as i said, IMO it would worth having exact value instead of "Program.Path" and "ProjectName"

Comment: Yes it does, but the file exists, as I wrote.
@jle I did that and tried to show each result in a MessageBox, but there were no MessageBoxes poping up, so I think there was nothing in the FileInfo-array.

Comment: Is this maybe because the name of the folder is "0.1.0.0"?

Comment: Problem solved. The problem was that I created the text file manually just for testing this and I gave it the name "info.txt", but it was already a text file -> Name should be "info.txt.txt" then. 
So, .NET does not lie, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

the name of folders and/or files are not any special name , reserved keywords ?

to trace this down how about trying the same thing with a new location , sample folder structure and different file name.

*ps.
I used your code - in linqpad it worked like charm (created folder structure to mimic and few files) surprised it fails for you.*

this is the code with little modification to work on my machine

```
void Main()
{
     string projectsPath = Path.Combine(@"D:\New folder", "Stackoverflow");
        string projectPath = Path.Combine(projectsPath);
        string packagesFolder = Path.Combine(projectPath, "Source");

    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(packagesFolder);
    DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = dInfo.GetDirectories();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in subDirs)
    {
        string packageInfo = String.Empty;
        string[] information;

        if (dir.EnumerateFiles().Any(item => item.Name == "test.txt"))
        {
            FileInfo file = dir.EnumerateFiles().First(item => item.Name == "test.txt");

            using (StreamReader sr = file.OpenText())
            {
                packageInfo = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: too curious for what it turns to be - updating my folder structure and modified code

Comment: Is this maybe because the name of the folder is "0.1.0.0"?

Comment: let me give a try, btw can you run tree /f > list.txt command in the root of this folder and share the list to confirm if name is issue

Comment: nop - D:\New folder\Stackoverflow\Source\0.1.0.0 passes test of reading info.txt